# How can I list all the combinations that meet certain criteria using Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, mathematical-optimization, operations

Which are the combinations that the sum of each digit is equal to 8 or less, from 1 to 88,888,888?

For example,
**70000001** = 7+0+0+0+0+0+0+1 = 8  *Should* be on the list
**00000021** = 0+0+0+0+0+0+2+1 = 3  *Should* be on the list.
**20005002** = 2+0+0+0+5+0+0+2 = 9  *Should not* be on the list.

```
Sub Comb()
Dim r As Integer 'Row (to store the number)
Dim i As Integer 'Range
r = 1
For i = 0 To 88888888
If i = 8
'How can I get the sum of the digits on vba?
ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1) = i
r = r + 1
End If
Else
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like a homework question... http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: (i) loop from 1 to 88,888,888 (ii) for each of those numbers calculate the sum of the figures (iii) if it adds up to 8, store it somewhere or print it (iv) give yourself a pat on the back...

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! What did you try so far, where are you stuck?

Comment: I know elegant solution using formulas only, but I'd like to see at least some efforts first)

Comment: does `777` equal **21** or **3** ?

Comment: This is the idea I have, but I'm stuck on calculating the number of digits:

Comment: Equals 21 @SeanCheshire

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean on Excel or on VB? @PeterL.

Comment: @user2061788 "using formulas only" means pure Excel)

Comment: @PeterL.  ... That's bragging. You don't have to give me an answer, but that is impossible. Even using this formula =SUM(VALUE(MID(B2,ROW($A$1:OFFSET($A$1,LEN(B2)-1,0)),1))) all the alternatives can't be generated with formulas only.

Comment: @user2061788 why not? all you need is to loop all numbers from 1 to 88,888,888 - also with the help of formulas))) that's even more trivial! However, I'm not sure whether Excel could happily handle 200M+ formulas in a single book, but that's another question)

Comment: @PeterL. I'm able to identify the numbers that meet the criteria in 1,000,000, that's why I asked here to get help and not have to do the proccess 88 times.

Comment: @user2061788 put this formula in `EVALUATE` vba wrapper - and you're done.

Comment: @PaulGrimshaw it was not for a homework. And now I solved it.     Sub Comb()
Dim i As Long
Dim r As Long
Range("B3").Select
r = 3
For i = 0 To 88888888
If ActiveCell.offset(-1, -1).Range("A1").Value < 8 Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 2) = i
r = r + 1
Else
End If
Next i
End Sub

Answer (score 1):

... Is this what you're looking for?

```
Function AddDigits(sNum As String) As Integer

Dim i As Integer

   AddDigits = 0
   For i = 1 To Len(sNum)
      AddDigits = AddDigits + CInt(Mid(sNum, i, 1))
   Next i

End Function
```

(Just remember to use `CStr()` on the number you pass into the function.

If not, can you explain what it is you want in a bit more detail.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The method you suggest is pretty much brute force. On my machine, it ran 6.5min to calculate all numbers. so far a challenge I tried to find a more efficient algorithm.

This one takes about 0.5s:

```
Private Const cIntNumberOfDigits As Integer = 9
Private mStrNum As String
Private mRng As Range

Private Sub GetNumbers()
    Dim dblStart As Double
    Set mRng = Range("a1")
    dblStart = Timer
    mStrNum = Replace(Space(cIntNumberOfDigits), " ", "0")
    subGetNumbers 8
    Debug.Print (Timer - dblStart) / 10000000, (Timer - dblStart)
End Sub


Private Sub subGetNumbers(intMaxSum As Integer, Optional intStartPos As Integer = 1)
    Dim i As Integer

    If intStartPos = cIntNumberOfDigits Then
        Mid(mStrNum, intStartPos, 1) = intMaxSum
        mRng.Value = Val(mStrNum)
        Set mRng = mRng.Offset(1)
        Mid(mStrNum, intStartPos, 1) = 0
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For i = 0 To intMaxSum
        Mid(mStrNum, intStartPos, 1) = CStr(i)
        subGetNumbers intMaxSum - i, intStartPos + 1
    Next i
    Mid(mStrNum, intStartPos, 1) = 0
End Sub
```

It can be sped up further by about factor 10 by using arrays instead of writing directly to the range and offsetting it, but that should suffice for now! :-)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, You can use a function like this:

```
Function isInnerLowr8(x As Long) As Boolean
    Dim strX As String, inSum As Long

    isInnerLowr8 = False
    strX = Replace(CStr(x), "0", "")
    For i = 1 To Len(strX)
        Sum = Sum + Val(Mid(strX, i, 1))
        If Sum > 8 Then Exit Function
    Next i
    isInnerLowr8 = True
End Function
```

Now change `If i = 8` to `If isInnerLowr8(i) Then`.